# Как перенести массив с одной страницы на другую

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть страница карточек (предположим, их 50 штук, и они лежат в массиве)
Юзер может выбрать любое количество карточек - выбранные карточки попадают в массив "selected".

Мне необходимо, чтобы массив selected сохранялся у юзера локально и появлялся на другой странице.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это проще всего реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 вариант.

Локальные хранилища: sessionStorage, localStorage, локальные базы данных, cookies и т.д.

**Плюсы**: отсутствие необходимости подключать дополнительные библиотеки

**Минусы**: без доп. библиотек нет поддержки реактивности "из коробки"; придется хранить JSON-представления ваших карточек, что может быть не очень хорошо, если карточки представлены объектами некого класса: информация о самом классе будет утеряна.

## 2 Вариант.

Хранить карточки в общем для обеих страниц родителе. При выборе карточек на одной странице, выбрасывать событие в родителя, откуда передавать обновленные данные на вторую страницу. Стандартный Vue-flow: пропы вниз, события наверх. Можно приукрасить интерфейс использованием `v-model`.

**Плюсы**: Vue-way. Так можно делать согласно общепринятым нормам вью. Все обновления реактивны. Отсутствие доп. зависимостей.

**Минусы**: засоряется локальный стейт родителя. Такое решение плохо скейлится.

## 3 Вариант.

Использовать библиотеку для глобального стейт менеджмента. Их множество под разные паттерны разработки и построения логики приложения, но для Vue существуют официально-поддерживаемые имплементации Flux-паттерна: VueX и Pinia. VueX - для Vue 2, Pinia - для Vue 3 (если грубо).

**Плюсы**: идеальное решение для вашей ситуации, подходит под нее лучше всего.

**Минусы**: необходимо внедрять доп. зависимости в проект

---

Выбирайте исходя из вашего конкретного кейса. Если интересует мое личное мнение, то я бы выбрал **вариант номер 3**.